# Averaging neighbours in a list

Tags: arithmetic, average

In a list of twelve numbers, the first number is 1 and the last number is 12.

```
1, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, 12 (assume the letters represent unknown numbers)
```

Each other number in the list is calculated by taking the average of its neighbours and adding 1. **The question is asking to find the largest number in this list.**

I have assumed the third number of the list to be x, then the second number can be calculated in terms of x:

1, $\frac{x+1}{2} + 1$, x

Continuing this process I got:

$1$, $\frac{x+3}{2}$, $x$, $\frac{3x-7}{2}$, $2x - 9$, $\frac{5x-33}2$, $3x - 26$, $\frac{7x-75}2$, $4x - 51$, $\frac{9x-133}2$, $5x - 84$, $12$

I found that x is equal to **21** and the biggest number in the list is **37**.

This method took a long time and is inefficient. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: With $x=21$ I find that the average of $\frac{9x-133}{2}$ and $12$ is $20$ which is different from $5x-84=21\,.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $x, y, z$ are three adjacent numbers, then $y = 1 + \frac{x+z}2$, which solves to $$z = 2y - x - 2$$

Also, let me call the values as $$1, a_1 = t, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_9, a_{10}, 12$$

Thus we can calculate

- $a_0 = 1 = 0t + 1$
- $a_1 = t - 0$
- $a_2 = 2t - 3$
- $a_3 = 2a_2 - a_1 - 2 = 3t-8$
- $a_4  = 2a_3 - a_2 - 2 = 4t - 15$
- $a_5 = 2a_4 - a_3 - 2 = 5t -24$

From which it appears that $$a_n = nt - n^2 +1$$
If this holds $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ then
$$\begin{align}a_{n+1} &= 2a_n - a_{n-1} - 2\\
&=2(nt - n^2 +1) - ((n-1)t - (n-1)^2 + 1) - 2\\
&=[2nt-(n-1)t] - [2n^2 - (n-1)^2 + 1] +[2 - 2]\\
&=[(n+1)t] - [n^2 + 2n]\\
&=(n+1)t - (n+1)^2 + 1\end{align}$$
And thus by induction, this holds for the remaining values, including $a_{11} = 12$.

So $$11t - 11^2 + 1 = 12\\t - 11 = 1\\t = 12$$
And we can calculate
$$a_1 = 12 - 0 = 12\\
a_2 = 24 - 3 = 21\\
a_3 = 36 - 8 = 28\\
a_4 = 48 - 15 = 33\\
a_5 = 60 - 24 = 36\\
a_6 = 72 - 35 = 37\\
a_7 = 84 - 48 = 36\\
a_8 = 96 - 63 = 33\\
a_9 = 108 - 80 = 28\\
a_{10} = 120 - 99 = 21\\
a_{11} = 132 - 120 = 12$$

Comment: While I didn't bother to do it, I could have figured out where the maximum would occur by noting that the $nt$ term increases by $t = 12$ as you move from $n$ to $n+1$, but the $-n^2$ term decreases by $2n+1$, thus the sequence increases until $2n+1$ passes $12$, after which it decreases.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve been trying to find a general rule for this pattern and your solution works perfectly.